# Groovyc error when compiling groovy source in Intellij IDEA: Invalid duplicate class definition of class

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, compilation

I'm compiling a project on Intellij IDEA that compiled perfectly con Eclipse but it keeps throwing `Invalid duplicate class definition of class` errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a ghost character at the start of the file.

I changed the encoding to ISO-8859-1 and back to UTF8 and the character (and the problem) got fixed.

Comment: Is that a compiler bug (misleading error message)? Is IDEA using a different compiler than Eclipse?

Comment: I guess there are differences as I found some blog post saying that in 14.1 you will be able to use groovy-eclipse as compiler.